# External message file for emailing with AngularJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to send an email with the content of a file (default_message.php) using AngularJS 1 and PHP.

**Frontend - AngularJS and HTML5** - *default_message.php*

```
<div ng-app="emailApp" ng-controller="MainController as Main">
   Dear {{Main.user}},
   I am sending you this email !!
</div>

<script>
   angular.module("emailApp",[])
     .controller("MainController", function(){
       var vm = this;
       vm.user = "Vlad";
     });
</script>
```

**Backend - PHP**

```
<?php
   $template = readfile("default_message.php"); // not compiled
   $to = "user@yahoo.com";
   $subject = "Hello";
   $body = $template;
   $from = "Sender";
   mail($to,$subject,$body,$from);
?>
```

---

How can I render angular first, and then read the file so I can mail it ?

Should I make a webservice that stores my data (in this case: **user**) and then display it as a PHP variable (Dear *$user_from_service*)?

Any hints how should I do this will be nice, thank you !!

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what you are trying to do. What does reading have to do with sending? Please narrow down specific problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl, I edited the post, I want to send an email with de message = the content of the file: default_message.php.